# Send SIGUSR1 output to sending console

Tags: php, console, signals, stdout

I'm building a PHP script that runs in an endless loop (until it recieves a SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGHUP) that's meant to run in a docker container.

I also added a simple SIGUSR1 hook that will simply print_r some statistics on the running job.  When I send a SIGUSR1 to the job with `kill -29 [PID]` the handler fires and outputs said data, but unfortunately it outputs it to the console that is serving as STDOUT, not the console that sends the kill.

How do I go about sending the script output to whichever console issued the SIGUSR1 kill command instead of STDOUT?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect output to a file?

```
$ php endless.php > /tmp/endless_output &
```

in another termnial:

```
$ kill -29 [PID]; cat /tmp/endless_output
```

It may worth to use a [named pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) instead of a regular file.

Comment: +1 An intuitive way, -1 Because you will lose the ability to read the program's output from the console itself.